# Getting false positive while checking whether alarm manager is set

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have two alarms 1. walk reminder 2. Tips Notification
The user can cancel, the walk reminder. The canceling process is working fine.

```
private void setWalkReminder(){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 50);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Intent walkIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "Started WALK SET");
    walkIntent.putExtra("alarmType", "walkReminder");
    PendingIntent walkPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, WALK_REMINDER, walkIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager walkAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    walkAlarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 180000 /*AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*/, walkPendingIntent);

    workoutEditor = workoutPrefs.edit();
    workoutEditor.putBoolean("walkReminderIsSet", true);
    workoutEditor.commit();
}

private void cancelWalkReminder(){
    Intent walkIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent walkPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, WALK_REMINDER, walkIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Log.d(TAG, "Walk Canceled");
    AlarmManager walkAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    walkAlarmManager.cancel(walkPendingIntent);
}
```

I am checking whether the alarm is set by the following method:

```
boolean walkAlarmDown = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, WALK_REMINDER,
            new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null);

    if (walkAlarmDown && workoutPrefs.getBoolean("walkReminderIsNeeded", true)){
        Log.d(TAG, "WALK REMINDER SET");
        setWalkReminder();
    } else if (!walkAlarmDown && !workoutPrefs.getBoolean("walkReminderIsNeeded", true)){
        Log.d(TAG, "WALK REMINDER CANCELED");
        cancelWalkReminder();
    } else {
        if(!workoutPrefs.getBoolean("walkReminderIsNeeded", true) && walkAlarmDown){
            Log.d(TAG, "Why is this false?");
        } else if (!walkAlarmDown && workoutPrefs.getBoolean("walkReminderIsNeeded", true)){
            Log.d(TAG, "proper functioning");
        }
}
```

if the user re-enables the reminder after it was canceled, then the reminder does not get set again . Log.d output is `proper functioning`. This is because walkAlarmDown still gives false. I believe this is because walkAlarmDown did not become true when the alarm was canceled. How to ensure walkAlarmDown should become true when alarm is canceled?

Alernatively, is it remaining true because my other alarm is enabled? Hence, only one alarm is canceled and another alarm remains active. It has a different Broadcast request code. So I presume it should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`walkPendingIntent` is still active even if the alarmmanager is canceled. The code, `walkAlarmManager.cancel(walkPendingIntent);`, should be followed by `walkPendingIntent.cancel()`. Now `walkAlarmDown` will give a true after canceling the alarm.

Comment: excellent answer!! Cancelling the Pending Intent is also required. Even Google's training guides miss this important point. https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-fundamentals/blob/master/StandUp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/standup/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @suku's answer the alarm does get cancelled when you call a cancel() on the AlarmManager.

```
walkAlarmManager.cancel()
```

But since you set or reset the alarm according to the existence of the Pending Intent you will need to explicitly cancel that as well.

Try reducing your periodic interval to 30 secs to test the firing or non-firing of the alarm. 
You will notice that the Alarm does indeed stop firing when you cancel it but the Pending Intent still remains active and that's what causes the false positive.

Basing your Alarm Management on the existence of the Pending Intent is in my opinion flawed logic. Alarm setting or resetting should be based on User intent.